# Cyclical Computational Graph

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to create a cyclical computational graph. The idea is simple and is detailed as follows:

- Initialise weights for a nueral network.
- Sample N lots of weights from a multivariate gaussian where the initialised weights are the mean of the gaussian.
- Evaluate some loss function for each set of weights.
- Update the weights appropriately.

An image of the basic approach can be seen as follows:

[image]

My current approach is to sample and update the weights during the training for loop. This is, however, slow, and I wanted to know if I could build this functionality into a computational graph and speed up my training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it all within the computation graph. For example, with a weights variable `W`:

```
NUM_SAMPLES = 10
STDDEV = 1

# Assuming W statically shaped, otherwise you'd use tf.shape and tf.concat
samples_shape = [0] + W.shape.as_list()
# Generate random numbers with W as mean
samples = tf.random_normal(samples_shape,
                           stddev=tf.constant(STDDEV, dtype=W.dtype),
                           dtype=W.dtype)
samples += W[tf.newaxis, :]
# The loss function should return a vector the size of
# the first dimension of samples
samples_loss = loss(samples)
idx = tf.argmin(samples_loss, axis=0)
# Update W
update_op = tf.assign(W, samples[idx])
```

Then you'd run `update_op` to perform one update step, or else go on with other operations using it as a control dependency:

```
with tf.control_dependencies([update_op]):
    # More ops...
```